# smtpd: warning: hostname example.com does not resolve to address 203.0.113.1

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix

One postfix instance at `sub.example.com` is pushing mail to `example.com` via LAN, which is both a mail server and a router:

```
Internet
|
|
203.0.113.1 
<example.com> (127.0.1.1 in /etc/hosts)
192.168.1.1
|
|
192.168.1.99
<sub.example.com>
```

Every time a LAN mail is received, a warning message is logged:

> postfix/smtpd[1337]: warning: hostname example.com does not resolve to address 203.0.113.1

However, the domain **does** resolve to the address, with only one A record (but no rdns):

```
# dig example.com
example.com.          3600   IN   A    203.0.113.1
# dig -x 203.0.113.1
..                       1   IN   PTR  new-customer.isp.example
```

While reverse DNS is NOT correct, that is not what the warning says, nor does it explain why it is only triggered by LAN mail. As confirmed via tcpdump, the LAN mail server `EHLO`s with `sub.example.com` - which is known to the postfix server as 192.168.1.99.

What is triggering the warning?

Comment: It doesn't related with `helo` command because this warning was produced when client first connect, after successfully three way handshake and before send any data.

Comment: Anyway, if client IP address was 192.168.x.x, why postfix detect it as 93.184.216.119?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

```
smtp_host_lookup = native
```

Will make the client postfix instance behave the way other mail clients on that systems would - using /etc/hosts IPs aswell - after which the target system will no longer complain about seeing the client connect from an outside IP although knowing it as 192.168.x.x.