# Mailserver complains about reverse DNS lookup on my Gateway

Tags: email-server, reverse-dns

I am presented a mail server setup, that is working well. There's only a small issue, which makes me think, there's something wrong in the DNS setup. It is a small setup with a Debian mail server (postfix/dovecot) behind a router. The router has port forwarding configured and is named "router.intern" (IP 10.0.0.1). So incoming mail gets delivered to the mail server and outgoing mails are also fine. Every time a mail gets delivered, there is a reverse DNS check for the delivering server IP to block spammers. But there's also a reverse DNS check on the router's name:

```
postfix/smtps/smtpd[8088]: warning: hostname router.intern does not resolve to address 123.123.123.123
```

(123.123.123.123 is a placeholder for its WAN IP.)

/etc/resolv.conf:

```
domain intern
nameserver 10.0.0.1
```

Why does the mail server try do resolve the router's DNS name over WAN? I'm at loss where to search as everything else is working fine.

Comment: Sounds like your router is doing either application level proxying or SNAT. You might want to check the configuration settings for its port forwarding.

Comment: No, checked that. None of both is set.

Comment: Is there any relevance to the address you've written as 123.123.123.123? Is this a literal part of the error or a placeholder you've invented for this question? If it's a placeholder please identify what it corresponds to.

Comment: Sorry, it's a placeholder. I just edited my post to reflect that.

Comment: Try giving a look here: http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html with particolar reference to paragraph "Proxy/NAT external network addresses"

Comment: Seemed promising, but did not help. Messages still appear.

Comment: Postfix wouldn't even see the IP address of the router under normal circumstances, so try [this solution from Serverfault](http://serverfault.com/a/639078/267016) to set `smtp_host_lookup = native`

Comment: Unfortunately no success. Still get the warning. Is there any kind of DNS caching? (I do NOT run any DNS service on Debian.)

Comment: Ah. Is the WAN address on your router or on your server? I've been assuming it's on the router and that your server is on a NAT network behind it. Is this the case?

Comment: Yes, it is. And it is the WAN address of the router.